# Akka IO Flush buffer

Tags: c#, scala, akka

I use Akka IO for connection between Scala and C# application. On scala side I write data to stream using Akka IO.

```
  case data: ByteString => connection ! Write(data)
```

But I want  to flush buffer because on C# side I read data from buffer and sometimes I read two message instead one and programs fails on parsing.
On C# side I read in such way:

```
 byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[2048];
 StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
 int numberOfBytesRead = 0;
 do
 {
      numberOfBytesRead = srReceiver.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
      message.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead));
  } while (srReceiver.DataAvailable);

  processMessage(message.ToString());
```

I think I should flush buffer after message sending but I don't know how to do it.
Maybe someone knows how to resolve this problem?

Comment: What is the actual underlying network protocol used here? What is "srReceiver"? In general, the right way to do this kind of thing is for the stream-based protocol to include a delimiter or byte count approach that allows the receiver to distinguish one message from another. For network protocols, flushing on the sender side is insufficient to _guarantee_ that the receiving side will see only a single message at a time. But without knowing exactly how Akka IO works and what you're actually doing on the C# side, it's hard to know exactly what the right thing to do is. Akka has no C# library?

Comment: It works through TCP. srReceiver is NetworkStream. I use json format for messages.

Answer (score 0):

Peter Duniho was right. I have added delimiter to every message and split it using this delimiter in processMessage method.

```
 private void ProcessMessage(String message)
    {

        string[] messages = message.Split(new String[] { END_PACKET }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach(String msg in messages)
        {
            string singleMessage = msg;
            if (msg.Contains(END_PACKET))
                singleMessage = msg.Substring(0, msg.LastIndexOf(END_PACKET));
            notify("Received : " + singleMessage);
            Request request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(singleMessage);
            onMessageReseived(request);
        }
    }
```